# Excel - Mind numbing issue- Form based league standing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, accumulate

Based on football data I am looking to create a league table which will give rankings of all the teams, the only difference is, each game week, teams will earn points based on the current ranking of the team they are playing.

So week by week, the excel document (with data added) will need to work out league position, work out who plays who, and then allocate points based on the result and the teams ranking of that week(which would be accumulated up to that week)

Ie, if Arsenal - Ranked 1st played Stoke Ranked 18 - and stoke won - Then the score stoke would receive for that week would be completely based on how high Arsenal was in the league..

Comment: Cool project! What's the question? On which piece of your implementation exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I can create a league table based on 3 points for a win and 1 point for a draw based on a whole list of results, but my main sticking point at the moment is being able to do that similarly on a week by week bases, using the current league ranking as the scoring mechanism.

Think I need to create a variable somehow for each of the teams which can give me an active league position then another linked field which can then accumulate the points on a rolling bases based on if its a win or draw linked to that position. - but has got the cogs turning. - Im no excel super whiz so hard to know

Comment: what is and isn't possible

Comment: @GolezTrol     ^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, but I'll take a crack at answering it.

If you have a worksheet with ranking by week, say with team in col A then rank in each column thereafter, you could then refer to this with a relative cell reference. If you need the ranking to be calculated, that could be done on the weekly ranking sheet. A formula on a worksheet for points calculated might end up being something like:

```
='points'!b2/'weeklyrank'!b2
```

This would divide points by a team's rank in the prior week, thus awarding more points for higher ranked teams, assuming that is the objective. There are all kinds of ways to tweak this. Hopefully this gets you started.

If you have a question about how to calculate the rankings, I would post it as another question, but with more detail.